# Is there a way to leave an argument out of the help using python argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I have an argument that is an internal debug flag and shouldn't be run by users who don't know what they are doing.
I realize that hiding it is in essence security by obscurity, but I'm not concerned about malice so much as incompetence.
Optparse had a SUPPRESS_HELP option, is there and argparse equivalent?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
parser.add_argument('--secret', help=argparse.SUPPRESS)
```

From here: http://argparse.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/argparse-vs-optparse.html

First Google result for `argparse suppress_help`, by the way.

Comment: yeah, I just found it, but you answered quicker than I could, I wonder why it's not in the argparse stdlib docs